# ASP.NET and C# retain dynamically added <li> content on post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

## Issue Definition

Using this basic example to reproduce the issue. When pressing button (causes post back) my `<li>` disappears and leaves behind an empty `<ol>` tag as expected. I am dynamically adding `<li>` tags in the C# code behind page see example provided. I am trying to retain this information across post backs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

#### ASP.NET Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="State.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ol id="myOl" runat="server">
            </ol>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### C# Code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnableViewState = false;
        if (TextBox1.Text == string.Empty)
            PopulateTextBoxes(TextBox1, myOl);
    }

    private static void PopulateTextBoxes(ITextControl textBox1, Control bulletedList)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "TextBox1";
        var li = new ListItem`enter code here`
        {
            Text = "Item1"
        };
        var bl = new BulletedList();
        bl.Items.Add(li);
        bl.DataBind();
        bulletedList.Controls.Add(bl);
    }
```

Comment: call the function `PopulateTextBoxes` inside Page_Init function, to render the controls  properly.

Comment: Remember: dynamically added controls will **not** automatically re-add themselves on post-back.  You must re-add them yourself (preferably within the `Init` stage of the [ASP.NET page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx))

Comment: I tried Page_Init and indeed it does retain my list. However the code example I supplied does a poor job of explaining my issue. Instead of a Text_Box I have two buttons. Button1 populates a multi line input box, and adds items to a bulleted list. My bulleted list disappears when I click Button2. I need to be able to retain my bulleted list and I can not populate the li during an Init because the bulleted list is based on information provided into the input box by the consumer and has to be populated by a button click.

Comment: rewrite your code with buttons instead of Textbox as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'm not sure what you are trying, but when you want a bullet list, that adds items on each button click try this one:

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"   Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
            <asp:BulletedList runat="server" ID="bulletList"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Codebehind**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             if (TextBox1.Text == string.Empty)
             {
                 PopulateTextBoxes();
             }
    }

    private void PopulateTextBoxes()
    {

            var li = new ListItem()
            {
                Text = "Item1"
            };
            bulletList.Items.Add(li);
    }
}
```

Here's some more info about the BulletedList control: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.UI.WebControls.BulletedList.%23ctor);k(BulletedList);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

When you disable ViewState, the page cannot maintain its state between postbacks, so you should disable it only, when you need to reduce network traffic.

Comment: This example actually works, the only problem is that during postback my css classes on the individual li items are disappearing. Anyway to keep it?

Comment: I don't know what your CSS looks like, but you can easily find out if it matches the generated HTML markup. Just use the developer tools of your favorite browser (usually F12 makes the tool window appear).
You can assign styles or classes to your controls by the Attributes or Style property. Or you define the CSS for the HTML tags according to the markup.